# MONGODB: $in operator not matching any record

Tags: mongodb

community!
I am in a weird situation. The direct equally check returns result, but when using $in I am not getting any records.

```
db.getCollection("voter").find({"id":{$in:["db1eefc5-09ad-4d4f-a31a-db63d8261913"]}})

db.voter.find({"id":{$in:["db1eefc5-09ad-4d4f-a31a-db63d8261913"]}})
```

Doesn't return anything.
[image]

```
db.voter.find({id: "db1eefc5-09ad-4d4f-a31a-db63d8261913"})
```

Returns the desired record.
[image]

Being more of a fullstack developer, I don't know what's happening in-depth, but I am sure that both things shall work ideally which is not the case here.

Extra info:
I have defined hashed unique indexes on `id`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is pretty simple:

On the first screen you're running your query against `admin` database

[image]

while second query gets executed against `crmadmin` db

[image]